# How to escape slashes in single-quoted strings?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

In Ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111):

```
str = '\&123'
puts "abc".gsub("b", str) => ab123c
puts "abc".gsub("b", "#{str}") => ab123c
puts "abc".gsub("b", str.to_s) => ab123c
puts "abc".gsub("b", '\&123') => ab123c
puts "abc".gsub("b", "\&123") => a&123c <--- This I want to achieve using temporary variable
```

If I change `str = '\&123'` to `str = "\&123"` it works fine, but I get `str` from `match` function, so I cannot specify it manually within parentheses. Is there any way to change the `'string'` to `"string"` behavior?

Comment: If you get str from match function, how can it have quotes? A string is a string and it makes no difference whether it was somewhere declared using single ore double quotes, or whatever it's origin is. Could you rephrase your question, to lower the level of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
str = '\&123' <-- the result of your match function
str = str.gsub(/\\/, '\\\\')
```

You may also want to take a look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html).

Comment: @stevo84 you can leave out the `g` option, as using `gsub` already makes it global.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Rubby isn't my prime language of development. I'm more a .NET guy.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the backslash:

```rb
puts "abc".gsub("b", '&123')
```

There is no need to protect the ampersand with a backslash inside
single-quoted string literals (unlike double-quoted ones).

Comment: the only problem is, I receive this string from match() function, and it contains a lot of other escaped strings as well (as it is an HTML)...

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a simpler way, however the code below works

```
> str = '\&123'
> puts "abc".gsub("b", str.gsub(/\\&/o, '\\\\\&\2\1'))
> => a\&123c
```

Answer (score 0):

@Valentin

-> I meant that str from match was not taken verbatim. Thus another (simpler) solution appeared, that I was not aware of....

`"abc".gsub("b") { str } -> a\&123c`